# chroot(2) alternative for POSIX 2008

Tags: c, linux, posix

Currently, I make use of chroot(2) using POSIX 1995, set by a compiler define that sets the X/Open version to v5. I'd like to switch to the newer POSIX 2008 (X/Open v7), but found out the chroot(2) is deprecated and not included there. LXC seems to be mentioned as an alternative, but my kernel does not support cgroups. What is the supposed replacement for chroot(2) for newer POSIX versions and where can I find information regarding other deprecated calls (e.g., usleep(3))?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670387/chroot-alternative

Comment: as for [`usleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html), use `nanosleep`: "Applications are recommended to use nanosleep() if the Timers option is supported"

Comment: @EdHeal: No, LXC is no alternative for me, since I do not have cgroups in my kernel -- I put this in my original posting.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Thanks for the hint regarding usleep!

Comment: @itecMemory - There was an alternative answer in the question

Comment: @EdHeal: Coffer is a wrapper around chroot. Posix 2008 does not have chroot(2) anymore, hence the question. Additionally, I'd like to code C and not introduce Python (which the target system also doesn't have, but that's a different story). I'm just wondering how chroot() can be thrown out of POSIX without an (obvious) alternative.